# ERROR PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure that is bringing up the error 'PL/SQL: Statement ignored'. This message is a little vague and I cant figure out why my procedure won't compile. All the procedure should do is check if the customer's delivery date is less then the SYSDATE and if it is delete and if not print 'customer can't be deleted'.

The code for the procedure is here:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
declare
   ordersCount pls_integer;
BEGIN
   select count(*) into ordersCount 
   from placed_orders 
   where fk1_customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id
   and delivery_date < sysdate;
if ordersCount = 0 then
THEN
DELETE FROM order_line
WHERE  order_line.FK1_order_id in
(SELECT order_id FROM placed_order
 WHERE placed_order.FK1_customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id
);
DELETE FROM placed_order
WHERE placed_order.FK1_customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;
total_customers := total_customers - 1;
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE 'Customer currently has a order been delivered';
END IF;
END;
```

And the error message is specifying PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"

thanks for any advice.

Comment: you can't use directly placed_order.delivery_date as placed_order is a table and you cannot put condition on table as shown in code. you can better get this value into one variable and then put condition over there. [your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459211/procedure-to-delete-only-if-database-higher-then-sysdate/16459824#16459824)

Comment: Hi yeah thanks for that that's what im doing but the code still isnt running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
IF placed_order.delivery_date < SYSDATE
```

doesn't make much sense - you cannot use a column like this (think about it: which of the rows in placed_order should be compared to SYSDATE? One? All?).

If you want to check whether this customer has a delivery that's already been delivered, you need an additional SELECT:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS       
  ordersCount pls_integer;
 begin
   select count(*) into ordersCount 
   from placed_orders 
   where fk1_customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id
   and delivery_date < sysdate;

   if ordersCount = 0 then
    -- your code for deleting the customer here
   else
    -- raise error, show message, ...
   end if;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I've edited what you said it makes much more sense. The final code if now in the question but when i run this code all i get is error 'PLS-00103' 'Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type '


do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Declare isn't needed for function/procedure bodies, just get rid of it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you do not edit the original code - this will confuse other readers. If you update the question, keep the original version and add your new version to the end of the question, clearly stating that it is an update.